# How to install http_pecl on PHP 5.x?

Tags: php, pecl

I am trying to install `pecl_http` on Ubuntu 14.04, however it reports to require PHP 7.

```
$ sudo pecl install pecl_http
pecl/pecl_http requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
pecl/raphf requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
pecl/propro requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
No valid packages found
install failed
$
```

Similarly on Debian:

```
pecl/pecl_http requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.17-0+deb8u1
pecl/raphf requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.17-0+deb8u1
pecl/propro requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.17-0+deb8u1
```

I can't find [changelog](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=pecl_http) any information that `pecl_http` is not backward compatible with PHP 5.x.

I tried with PHP 7.0 and it installed successfully, but is there anything I can do to install it with PHP 5.x?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to find out what version of `pecl_http` doesn't require the current version of PHP, and then specifically install that one. According to the documentation:

> "Package[-version/state][.tar]" : queries your default channel's server
>   (pear.php.net) and downloads the newest package with
>   the preferred quality/state (stable).
>
> To retrieve Package version 1.1, use "Package-1.1," to retrieve
>   Package state beta, use "Package-beta."  To retrieve an uncompressed
>   file, append .tar (make sure there is no file by the same name first)

And [according to the changelog](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=pecl_http), `pecl_http` 3.0 is the first PHP 7 compatible version, so maybe try the previous.

Final answer: you'd be looking for `sudo pecl install pecl_http-2.5.5`

Answer (score 4):

This question has an accepted answer, but I will add my 2 cents to the subject:

Based on your PHP version:

- for PHP 7 use 'pecl install oci8'
- for PHP 5.2 to 5.6 use 'pecl install oci8-2.0.12'
- for PHP 4.3.9 to 5.1 use 'pecl install oci8-1.4.10'

OCI8 **2.0.12** is the final release for **PHP 5.6.x**

OCI8 **2.1.x** is only valid for **PHP 7**

**Installing OCI8 for PHP 5.6.31**:

```
[root@server bin]# ./pecl install oci8-2.0.12
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading oci8-2.0.12.tar ...
Starting to download oci8-2.0.12.tar (1,615,360 bytes)
....
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
...
```

Expected output for [PHP 5.6.31 and OCI8 2.0.12](https://gist.github.com/divitoDBA/24a287962eff8ba1e4b74d38efaeae69)

This is the easiest way to install OCI8 support.

Comment: Did OP need pecl_http and not oci8 or am I not getting something right?